# Entity framework update model from database not generating cs class for newly added table in tt class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am using entity framework 5 with visual studio 2012.

I do have an existing model. Now I want to add a new table to that existing model. For that I have opened the edxm file and using right click I updated the model successfully.

Now, in "Model Browser" under "EntityTypes" for model, I can see the table name exists. But in Solution Explorer it is not showing the auto-generated .cs file for the table I have added newly under .tt file.

I tried "run custom tool" but it has not generated the class. Also have restarted the Visual Studio but result is the same.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Any experts available..?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Problems

1. In case you have table name `tblEmployee` in Database But after the adding 'Entity Data Model' you have Changed Entity `tblEmployee` to `Employee` in EDMX file then Save and Build. But Classes for Changed Name are not Generated Automatically in Model1.tt file.
2. When "**Update Model From Database**" for adding new table same Problem occurs.
3. Also not available in MVC When creating view with Model Class/Create Controller With Actions using EntityFramework

This problem is for early version of VS2012.This problem is solved in upgraded version of VS2012.

**Solution**

we have solution for this with early version of VS2012 & EF 5.0

Follow steps

1. Right click On Model1.tt and select 'Run Custom Tool' save and Build Now see classes are generated.
2. Right click On Model1.Context.tt and select 'Run Custom Tool' save and Build Now see property IN Context class is generated like

   ```
   public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
   ```

Save and Build Solution

```
Model1Context context=new Model1Context();
List<Employee> empList= context.Employees.ToList();
```

This worked for me.
But Keep in mind that still EF 6.0 not able to make Scaffolding when 'creating controller and view using entityframework' in MVC with this viersion of VS2012.
You must Use EF 5.0 or update VS2012 with new update.

Comment: Thanks. I had resolved it before still I am accepting this answer as it might be helpful to others.

Comment: This was so helpful, thanks. Normally auto code generation works for me fine but this time I added the entity edmx to an ASP.NET website project under App_Code folder which might have caused issues in the models not being generated on adding a new table from database using "Update Model From Database".

Comment: This was SUPER helpful. I have been struggling quite a while to get past this issue.It worked for me. Thanks! Keep up the good work.

Comment: Thank you very much I have been involved in this for a week

Comment: When I Run Custom Tool on Model.tt, it deletes the content of Model.Context.cs.  I suggest people make a safe copy first.

Answer (score 6):

Resolved it myself.

The problem was in files *filename*.Context.tt and *filename*.tt.

The diagram file name for variable `const string inputFile` specified in both of the files were different than the existing diagram file (*.edmx* file). Updated it with existing diagram file name and then updated model from database. Working fine now.

Comment: Can you please explain it?

Comment: This is great answer.Delete your model completely and add new data model.So the files will create again files and fixed.Do not just delete tables in model diagram.Delete model file and any nested files.

Answer (score 4):

In this case what i do is i just delete the exciting model and then click on add and just add your newly added table for there!

If this is the bug with the edmx file located in a folder it is now fixed - download and install VS 2012 Update 1. You can get it from:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-visual-studio-2012-update

Answer (score 3):

I have added primary key to the new table. That resolves problem.